# efficient way to solve $Ax = b$ where $A_{ij} = 0$ for every $i > j+1$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square non-singular matrix. Moreover, $A_{ij} = 0$ for every $i> j+1$ , meaning that in every column, from the elements that are under the diagonal, only the first element under the main diagonal is not zero.

The task is to find an efficient method to solve $Ax = b$.

I don't really have any idea, besides to use Gaus' eliminations as always. I think it will take $O(n^2)$

I can't think of anything better.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to say **only the first element under the main diagonal is not zero** shouldn't you have $A_{ij} =0$ whenever $i \ne j+1$?

Comment: I meant only from the elements that are under the diagonal. I will fix it

Comment: This is a [Hessenberg matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation#Triangularization for how to transform such a matrix to upper triangular form

Comment: Okay, I see, but is it better then just do Gaus eliminations?